# Does devtools::build_readme() use {webshot2} (if installed)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, devtools, flextable, webshot

I am currently [building a package](https://github.com/ian-curtis/gvsu215) for a rather specific audience. The package itself is coming along nicely but I am having trouble getting my README.Rmd to convert to a README.md (using `devtools::build_readme()`. Some functions in my package output `ggplot` objects and these render to GitHub README fine. However, other functions output `flextable` objects, which are inherently HTML and which GitHub does not like to display.

I was hoping that `build_readme()` would use `{webshot2}` to take a snapshot of my tables for use in non-HTML formats, such as `github_document` but this doesn't seem to be the case. I do have `{webshot2}` installed and Google Chrome is my primary browser so I have that. My README displays fine on my documentation page (since it's an HTML page).

Is there something I'm missing with `build_readme()` or `{webshot2}`? Or is this really something that isn't possible right now and I should direct all users to my documentation's copy of the README rather than the GitHub version?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a simple way to do this, but `flextable` supports saving a table to a PNG file, and you could do that and then include the file using `knitr::include_graphics()`.

For example, your first example could be modified to look like this:

````
```{r include=FALSE}
flextable_to_image <- function(x, ...) {
  if (inherits(x, "flextable")) {
    filename <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    flextable::save_as_image(x, filename)
    knitr::include_graphics(filename)
  } else
    knitr::normal_print(x)
}
```

```{r num-sum, message = FALSE, render = flextable_to_image}
library(gvsu215)

num_sum(mtcars, ~wt, na_rm = TRUE)
```
````

It's probably best to only print `flextable` objects in a chunk that uses `render = flextable_to_image` because the `else` clause is overly simplified.  It might also be a good idea to `unlink()` the `filename` after conversion.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me sadly. I ended up submitting an issue on GitHub but I really appreciate your help! I learned something new today (the render = option)!

Comment: @icurtis, if you don't get fast action from your issue, you should expand your question or ask a new one to explain what went wrong.  Someone might be able to fix it.